# Unity3d c# weapon method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a tongue like weapon that fires from the player and then retracts back bringing back any enemies it touches.  I was looking at linecast or using a mesh.

Any advice for what my work best?

The game is 3d with the player stationary in the scene and enemies flying around him.  The idea was to use touch/mouse position to decide where the tongue would fire too but the 3d to 2d is causing all sorts of issues.

Any advice of where to start greatly received,  I think trying two or three different approaches has left me a little bit muddled.  Inspiration needed!

Comment: This sort of question is too broad.  Such questions tend to lead to opinionated responses not fitted to SO.  Please see the SO question guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you'll want to do, or something to help you get started.

First you have to know exactly what you're doing to detect contact. This can be used with a trigger event with some sort of trigger box of the object.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider object)
{
  // The collision code here. Just keep reading,
}
```

Now it comes down to bringing the object back. You can easily just use `object.gameObject.transform.position` and set a new position. However this will cause the object to "jump" because you're modifying the coordinates of the object directly. So if you don't care to much about that..here's something in full you could do. This can hopefully get you started.

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider object)
{
    if(object.tag == "enemy")
    {
        object.transform.position = new Vector3(0,0,0);
    }
}
```

This is an example of something you could do.

Side note: You may need to change `object.` to `object.gameObject.`.

I hope I've helped you enough to get you started. :)

Comment: I suggest using interpolation at the end so that the enemy is pulled at a constant rate using the Update loop for a given amount of time then multiplying by Time.DeltaTime in order to make a smoother animation.

Comment: Thank you @OrrenRavid I completely forgot to mention that in the original answer. 
I'll see if I can write it up a bit later to give a more detailed answer as I am currently very busy.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Any advice for dealing with the 3D to 2D problem? Whenever I send a linecast out to mouse position or touch position it does not correspond to the position onscreen.  Sometimes it is close other times totally the wrong side.

Comment: I have the enemy moving around nicely towards a game plane but my problem is firing a the 'projectile tongue' and hitting the enemy and the returning back to the mouth.  Nothing I seem to try looks convincing or appropriate.

Comment: Hi all, anyone add to this answer.  Unfortunately it does not address my main issue which is getting the correct direction from a mouse input/touch position for a raycast/linecast.